# show only the current month in datepicker and remaining all months should be disabled using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, datepicker

I have datepicker showing only months.
It should show only current month and remaining months should be disabled.

I have tried with `min-date` and `max-date`, but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
  readonly="readonly" ng-model="xxxx"
  min-mode="'month'" min-date="startmnth" max-date="endmnth"
  datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM" is_open="status.date_opened" 
  ng-required="true" placeholder="YYYY-MM" 
  datepicker-options="datepickerOptions" 
  datepicker-mode="'month'" ng-click="openfromDate($event)" 
  show-button-bar="false">
```

JS:

```
$scope.startmnth = new Date().getMonth()
$scope.endmnth = new Date().getMonth()

$scope.datepickerOptions = {
    startingDay: 1,
};

$scope.openfromDate = function ($event) {                    
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();        
    $scope.status.date_opened = true;
 };
```

Comment: why you are not using <md-datepicker> tag for that. It will definitely going to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can add "dateDisabled: this.disabledDates" as part of your options, and then create a function like this:

```
this.disabledDates = function(data) {
    var date = moment(data.date);
    //check date and return true/false to disable/enable
    return false;//to disable
}
```